# KMDF Driver INF file error KMDF: 1280 and 1212

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf, wdf

This is my current Code:

```
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=%ClassName%
ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171}
Provider=%ProviderName%
CatalogFile=hidriver.cat
DriverVer=01/07/2018
PnpLockdown = 1


[SourceDisksNames]
1=%DiskName%,,,
[SourceDisksFiles]
hidriver.sys=1
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Microsoft,NT$ARCH$.6.1
[Microsoft.NT$ARCH$.6.1]
%DeviceName%=DefaultInstall,root\hidriver

[DefaultInstall.NT]
CopyFiles=Files
[Files]
hidriver.sys

[DefaultInstall.NT.HW]
AddReg=HWAddReg
[HWAddReg]
HKR,,"LowerFilters",0x00010008,"hidriver"

[DefaultInstall.NT.Services]
AddService=hidriver,0x00000000,hidriverService
AddService=mshidkmdf,0x00000002,mshidkmdfService
[hidriverService]
DisplayName=%ServiceName%
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\hidriver.sys
[mshidkmdfService]
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\mshidkmdf.sys

[DefaultInstall.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService=hidriver,KmdfLibrary
[KmdfLibrary]
KmdfLibraryVersion=$KMDFVERSION$

[Strings]
DeviceName="VARIABLE_1"
DiskName="VARIABLE_2"
ProviderName="VARIABLE_3"
ManufacturerName="VARIABLE_4"
ServiceName="VARIABLE_5"
ClassName="VARIABLE_6"
```

Visual Studio is throwing these errors:

1. 1280 Class name and ClassGuid mismatch, expecting Class "Sample" for ClassGuid "{78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171}".
2. 1212 Cannot have both [Manufacturer] and [DefaultInstall] sections.

How can i solve these errors?